# Функция входа пользователя в Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pyrogram

Такая проблема, нужно сделать функцию которая будет осуществлять вход пользователя через телеграм бота с помощью Client.sign_in() но получаю ошибку, что время кода истекло. А поддержка телеграмма говорит следующее:

> Никто не получил доступ к Вашей переписке, потому что входа в аккаунт не произошло. Код был введен верно, но вход был заблокирован, поскольку ранее Вы сообщили этот код со своего аккаунта.

Как я понимаю это сам тг блокирует, но не понимаю почему.

вот фрагменты из кода:

```
  app = Client(name='name',api_id=api_id,api_hash=api_hash)
  app.connect()
  ... 
  @dp.message_handler(state=ClientStatesGroup.number)
async def number_set(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['number'] = message.text
  async with state.proxy() as data:
    sCode_coroutine = app.send_code(data['number'])
    sCode = await sCode_coroutine
    data['sCode'] = sCode

  await ClientStatesGroup.next()
  await message.answer(text='А теперь отправь код который пришел в телеграм')
  ....
@dp.message_handler(state=ClientStatesGroup.code)
    async def code_set(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
         async with state.proxy() as data:
             data['code'] = message.text

         async with state.proxy() as data:
             await app.sign_in(data['number'], data['sCode'].__dict__['phone_code_hash'], data['code'])
     await message.answer(text='Все успешно сделано', reply_markup=startkb)
```

---